# Unresolved Android Dependencies

Tags: android

Keep getting a sync error on this line of code.

**implementation 'com.android.support:support.media.compat:28.0.0'**

No idea what it means, and I have tried multiple times to change the library with no luck

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0:15.0.0'
```

}

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: it should be like this   com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0

Comment: I've tried this already and it doesn't work

Comment: What error are you getting exactly ? anything in logcat ?

Comment: Failed to resolve: firebase-core-15.0.0
<a href="openFile:C:/FreshAndroidExamples/FirebaseExample/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: Have you tried using 16.0.0 instead of 16.0.0:15.0.0 in your firebase dependency?

Comment: Yes tried this also and it didnt work.

Comment: Then please make sure you are not missing any step from this official link : https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

Answer (score 0):

try with this
[docs](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/support-media-compat/28.0.0-alpha1)

```
compile group: 'com.android.support', name: 'support-media-compat', version: '28.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Thanks but tried this already and it didn't work. Still getting this error.

Comment: Failed to resolve: firebase-core-15.0.0
<a href="openFile:C:/FreshAndroidExamples/FirebaseExample/app/build.gradle">Open File</a>

Comment: @MichealBeausang did you added google() maven repository to build.gradle?
https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup?hl=es-419

Comment: No i havent done this, but i didnt think i needed to because it does it automatically?

Comment: @MichealBeausang  no it doesnt set automatically

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug in the latest version of Android studio 3.2 which adds the buggy dependency of firebase when we add it through the firebase tools.

I have came across the **same issue** when I added the firebase to my project, but adding this line of code manually helped me to resolve the issue.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
```

You can checkout the dependency in the [official firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#available_libraries)

And also the media compat library should be like this check out the [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages#v4-media-compat)

```
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28.0.0'
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Thanks for the tips. So I've done as you have said but I am still getting this error

Comment: Then please add both gradle files module and project level, that might help and also the error you are getting now..